# save to file-> Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone

I have a problem. I create a code, but I don't know why this program save nothing. All time file "phone.xml" looks like the same. Why?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("contacts_class/phone.xml");
XElement xEle = Load();
xEle.Add(new XElement("Contact",
    new XElement("FirstName", name),
    new XElement("LastName", surname),
    new XElement("PhoneNumber", number)));
var file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("phone.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, file))
{
    xDoc.Save(stream);
}
```

///

Answer (score 1):

You never changed `xDoc`.

Modifying an unrelated variable does not affect `xDoc`.